# Descargar archivo zip laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo este codigo que me genera un zip con las imagenes que guardo en el directorio download, estas imagenes son previamente seleccionadas...

**Ejemplo para el primer envio:**

Selecciono imagen1, imagen2, imagen3 e imagen4, por lo tanto en mi directorio download solo estaran estas 4 imagenes y por supuesto el zip se creara con dichas imagenes.

**Código para el primer envió**

```
  $checked = $request->input('catalog');

     foreach($checked as $check){
        $path = File::where('name',$check)->select('real_path')->first();
        $img = \Image::make($path->real_path);
        $img->save(public_path('download'). '/'. $check);
           }

        $files = \File::files('download');
        \Zipper::make(public_path('download/download.zip'))->add($files);
        return response()->download(public_path('download/download.zip'));
```

**Ejemplo para el segundo envió:**

En esta ocasión solo selecciona imagen1, imagen2, entonces necesito que el zip solo contenga esas 2 imágenes, por lo que se me ocurrió hacer esto:

Eliminar el contenido del directorio download si el download.zip existe:

```
 if (\File::exists('download/download.zip')) {
     $directory_cuts   = public_path('download');
     $success   = \File::cleanDirectory($directory_cuts);
    }

    foreach($checked as $check){
       $path = File::where('name',$check)->select('real_path')->first();
       $img = \Image::make($path->real_path);
       $img->save(public_path('download'). '/'. $check);
    }

    $files = \File::files('download');
    \Zipper::make(public_path('download/download.zip'))->add($files);
     return response()->download(public_path('download/download.zip'));
```

El código funciona en los siguientes puntos:

- Elimina el contenido del directorio download.
- Genera las nuevas imagenes seleccionadas.
- Genera el archivo zip, con las imagenes generadas.

Pero no funciona en el mas importante el cual es descargar el ZIP.

Obtengo el siguiente error:

```
The file "C:\wamp\www\Petro\public\download\download.zip" does not exist
```

Hay algo malo en mi código??

Y si hay alguna otra forma de descargar múltiples archivos, tambien me gustaria saberlo.

Answer (score 1):

recuerda que acceder a un archivo del disco duro, es malo de por sí.

El problema es que lo quieres traer de un directorio privado del sistema (es decir wamp/www),

el cual se ingresa desde c:/wamp/www/... etc.

El problema es que te lo genera con las diagonales inversas c:\wamp\www ... por lo que no interpreta el sistema.

Así que 1 de 2, o trabajas en un linux, o cambias la ruta de acceso mi amigo.